# How to setting up MongoDB on macOS?

Tags: mongodb, bash, macos, server

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/mongodb/setting-up-a-local-mongodb-database#setting-up-mongodb-on-macos). I start successfully the MongoDB server with this path :

```
mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb --logpath /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log --fork
```

However, after I when to start up the MongoDB shell to connect to and manage the server, but when I type this following command in my bash :

```
mongo
```

I receive this error :

```
-bash: mongo: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily install mongo with Brew Tool on MacOS

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew update
brew install mongodb-community@6.0
```

Btw, there's the official documentation on mongodb website here: 
[MongoDBOfficial](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)

Hope this help, 
Regards.

Comment: Forgot to say, if you don't have Brew, go here: https://brew.sh/

Comment: I installed mongo with Brew Tool on MacOS, as you suggest but I still get the same error. However, I am able to get access to the shell through MongoDB Compass.

Comment: still says, `mongod: command not found`